# Sequelize inner join with conditions

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have tried to find a solution for my case but couldn't.
I have 3 tables:

```
Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  permissions: {
    type: Sequelize.JSONB
  }
});

EmployeeRole = sequelize.define('EmployeeRole', {
  employeeId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  roleId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
  }
});
```

And I get employees from other source outside of sequalize.

I have created a adummy object for employees table in the model file as follows:

```
const Employee = sequelize.define('Employee', {});
```

with the following associations

```
 EmployeeRole.belongsTo(Role, { foreignKey: 'roleId', sourceKey: 'id' });
 EmployeeRole.belongsTo(Employee, { foreignKey: 'employeeId' });
```

I using the employee ID, how can I retrieve the employee's Roles?

### Update

The target query I'm trying to achieve is the following where I supply the employee ID:

```
select * from "Roles" as r,"EmployeeRoles" as er
where r.id = er."roleId"
and er."employeeId" = 2035
```

Answer (score 2):

From your description, i assume each `Employee` can have many `Role` and each `Role` belongs to many `Employee`. As a result this has many to many associations.

Your association will resemble as,

```
Employee.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
  through: model.EmployeeRole,
  foreignKey: 'employeeId'
});

Role.belongsToMany(models.Employee, {
  through: model.EmployeeRole,
  foreignKey: 'roleId'
});
```

You can retreive employee roles as,

```
models.Employee.findAll({
  include: {
    model: models.Role,
    through: {
      attributes: ['id']
    }
  }
})
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm getting "ReferenceError: models is not defined". Where "models"  shall come from?

Comment: `models` will be imported from `/models/index.js` file, where sequelize connection and associations happen

Answer (score 1):

Hope you need only an inner join (You don't have any condition )
Try something like this

```
Employee.findOne({
    where:{
        id:2330
    },
    include:[
    {model:EmployeeRole,}
    include:[
    {model:Role,attributes:['name']}
    ]   
    ]
})
```

Comment: I'm getting anerror on the 2nd include. Please note that my database doesn't have an Employee table because I get it as a condition from outside service.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.
The following seems to return the correct values

```
EmployeeRole.findAll({where:{employeeId: empId},
    include: [
      {model: Role,attributes:['id','name','permissions'],required: true}
    ],
    attributes:['roleId']
  })
```